# How to make a webview NOT clickable in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, webview, webkit

I want to implement a webview in Swift for an iOS application where I just want to display the content of a given website. The implementation below works but I have 2 requirements that I don't know how to implement:

1. I want the user not to be able to interact with the page displayed in any way. So if for example there is a link, the user cannot click on that. Same goes for any other element of the page, like images, etc. Is there a way to do so? In practice, the website content would need to be served as if it was a picture of the content, without the possibility to interact with individual elements of the page.
2. I want that the address of the website is never visible to the user. In my implementation below, that seems to be the case, but I am not sure if that would work in any condition and if there is a safer way to ensure that the web address is never displayed to the user (even when for example iOS informs the user that there was an issue loading the page, etc).

What I have in ViewController.swift is below:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
            webView = WKWebView()
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
            view = webView
        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        let url = URL(string: "my-website-here")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the closing bracket of the func `override func viewDidLoad()` try implementing this

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
 decisionHandler(.cancel)
}
```

also just under `webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))`

add

```
navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```